# Rails 3 - saving data with using CONTROLLER.new(params[:controller])

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I am newbie in Rails and now I am solving situation, how to most effectively save data into database. My form contains 10 inputs (= 10 columns in table) and the 11th input is for file.

If I'll used

```
@mail = Mail.find(params[:id]).save
```

So I'll get something like this to my table (colum):

```
 --- !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile 
content_type: image/jpeg
headers: |
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mail[logo]"; filename="panama-city-15.jpg"
  Content-Type: image/jpeg

original_filename: panama-city-15.jpg
tempfile: !ruby
```

But I need to store only name of file - "panama-city-15.jpg". So the option is for every input do separate saving, something like this:

```
@mail = Mail.new(:mail_id => @mail_source.id.to_i,
                 :a => params[:mail][:a],
                 :b => params[:mail][:b],
                 ...
                 :logo => params[:mail][logo].original_filename)
```

But I think is a bit unnecessary to type 10 single lines due "params[:mail][logo].original_filename"...

So I would like to ask you, if exist any better way, how to solve this situation...

Comment: If you write "`@mail = Mail.find(params[:id]).save`" then your `@mail` variable will have the value true or false. The `save` method does not return the saved object. Beware!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way of assigning attributes to models:

```
@mail = Mail.find(params[:id])
@mail.attributes = params[:mail]
if @mail.save
  #...and so on.
```

You may define all the necessary accessors, which do not need to be the same as the columns in the database, and you may want to read about [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) method.

So, if you want to store the original filename of an uploaded file, you may do this:

```
# Beware: this is only an example of technical possibility.
# Do not handle uploaded files in this way!
#
def logo=(f)
  self[:logo] = f.original_filename
end
```

But I think it's a bad idea. If you store only original filename, then you will lost the file. It will be deleted from the server just after you process the request. You have to store the file somewhere.

```
# This may work for you.
#
def logo=(f)
  return unless f.respond_to?(:read) && f.respond_to?(:original_filename)
  f.rewind
  self[:logo_content] = f.read
  self[:logo_filename] = f.original_filename
end
```